# Android OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener and orientation change

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I've made a custom `PreferenceScreen` which programatically creates some preferences.

It creates some `ListPreference`s and a custom `PreferenceCategory` inside certain `PreferenceScreen`.

These preferences are created dynamically because their values and visibility depend on values of each other. E.g. you can select an item which can either have or don't have certain color variations (will add list preference) or certain attachments (will add a set of checkbox preferences).
This behavior is implemented using `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Now, if device is rotated in main screen of preferences, everything works as usual. But if device was rotated when `PreferenceScreen` was visible, it won't recreate UI. It won't modify it at all until I return back to main preferences screen and rotate device again to force `onResume`.

The strangest part here is that on rotation within sub-`PreferenceScreen` all events are working as expected - I see change listener firing up, it successfully finds necessary `PreferenceScreen` and recreates all preferences inside it. But nothing changes visually - UI of this `PreferenceScreen` won't get updated.

I've tested this on Nexus7 with Android 4.4. Please advice how to deal with this misbehavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could use onConfigurationChanged of the Activity - class to detect and trace this behavior and then manually call onResume.

```
@Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      // Checks the orientation of the screen
     if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
     ....
     } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
     ....
     }
}
```

Comment: But `onResume` gets called - it registers change listener which also 'works' and recteates preferences items - I just don't see these changes on screen.